# Java 8, how to add filtering and mapping into Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

```
protected Map<String, String> test(List<String> ids) {
    return ids
          .stream()
          .map(e -> fun1(e, "1"))
          .filter(out -> out.length() == 3)
          .collect(Function.identity(), ______) (what should i write here, if I want the out put of fun1, writing out here dose not work)
} 
public String fun1(String one, String two) {
    return one + two;
}
```

simple input: ("1", "23", "34", "6")

then the output should be {("23", "233"), ("34","343")}

the reason is that for "23" "34" add "3", it length is  3 then put them into map

This is sudo code, not the real case I used. So I tried to do  mapping filtering then collect to map, but for the blank there I dont how to reference the output of Fun1. I know Java 9 has some solution using filtering. any solutions for Java 8

Comment: What does "using filtering" mean? Can you provide example input and output?

Comment: If you're trying to map the original strings in `ids` to their `fun1` output, then you need to keep both values when you run `map()`. Otherwise, skip `map`, but then you'd miss the filter.

Comment: No, there isn't really a Java 8 solution.  Do the filtering in the stream, not the Collector.

Comment: I assume the key in your map is the value before mapping and the value part is the object after mapping? But once you map it using `fun1`, the `Function.identity()` refers to the mapped value and not the original one.

Comment: Could you please see the input and ouput, it might be help to understand what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

To map the original values of the `List` into the result of applying `fun1()`, you have to `map` each element to a pair of elements. You can use, for example, `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` class.

```
public class Test
{
    public String fun1(String one, String two) {
        return one + two;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> test(List<String> ids) {
        return ids.stream()
                  .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<String,String>(e, fun1(e, "3")))
                  .filter(e -> e.getValue ().length() == 3)
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
    } 

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Test instance = new Test ();
        System.out.println(instance.test (List.of ("1", "23", "34", "6")));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{23=233, 34=343}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. get error from last line (Map.Entry :: getKey)

Comment: Error message: Non-static method can not be referenced from a static context

Comment: @shuangquanfu that's strange. the code passes compilation for me. Did you `import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;`?

Comment: Yes I did add that import

Comment: @shuangquanfu are you sure you are using the exact code posted in the answer? Please try the edited answer (I put the methods inside a class), to make sure you don't have any additional code that causes problems.

Comment: Solved fogetting add( <String, String>)

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static Map<String, String> test(List<String> ids) {
    return ids.stream()
              .filter(id -> fun1(id, "3").length() == 3)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), id -> fun1(id, "3")));
}

private static String fun1(String one, String two) {
    return one + two;
}
```